# Crouching is Not Working But Sliding and Sprinting is - Solved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    private float moveSpeed;
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float sprintSpeed;

    public bool sliding;
    public bool sprinting;

    public float groundDrag;

    [Header("Jumping")]
    public float jumpForce;
    public float jumpCooldown;
    public float airMultiplier;
    bool readyToJump;

    [Header("Crouching")]
    public float crouchSpeed;
    public float crouchYScale;
    private float startYScale;

    [Header("Keybinds")]
    public KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    public KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
    public KeyCode crouchKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;

    [Header("Ground Check")]
    public float playerHeight;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    bool grounded;

    [Header("Slope Handling")]
    public float maxSlopeAngle;
    private RaycastHit slopeHit;
    private bool exitingSlope;

    [Header("Sliding")]
    public float maxSlideTime;
    public float slideForce;
    private float slideTimer;
    public float slideSpeed;

    public float slideYScale;

    [Header("References")]
    public Transform orientation;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Input")]
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float verticalInput;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    public MovementState state;
    public enum MovementState
    {
        walking,
        sprinting,
        crouching,
        sliding,
        air
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;

        readyToJump = true;

        startYScale = transform.localScale.y;
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // ground check
        grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);

        MyInput();
        SpeedControl();
        StateHandler();

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(sprintKey) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
            sprinting = false;

        // handle drag
        if (grounded)
            rb.drag = groundDrag;
        else
            rb.drag = 0;

        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey) && sprinting)
            StartSlide();

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey) && sliding)
            StopSlide();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();

        if (sliding)
            SlidingMovement();
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        // when to jump
        if (Input.GetKey(jumpKey) && readyToJump && grounded)
        {
            readyToJump = false;

            Jump();

            Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
        }

        // start crouch
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, crouchYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * 5f, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(crouchKey) && sprinting)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, slideYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * 5f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            sliding = true;
            moveSpeed = slideSpeed;
        }

        // stop crouch
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(crouchKey))
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
            sliding = false;
        }
    }

    private void StateHandler()
    {
        // Mode - Crouching
        if (Input.GetKey(crouchKey))
        {
            state = MovementState.crouching;
            moveSpeed = crouchSpeed;
        }

        // Mode - Sliding
        if(Input.GetKey(crouchKey) && sprinting)
        {
            state = MovementState.sliding;
            moveSpeed = slideSpeed;
        }

        // Mode - Sprinting
        else if (grounded && Input.GetKey(sprintKey) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            state = MovementState.sprinting;
            moveSpeed = sprintSpeed;

            sprinting = true;
        }

        // Mode - Walking
        else if (grounded)
        {
            state = MovementState.walking;
            moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
        }

        // Mode - Air
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.air;
        }
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        // calculate movement direction
        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

        // on slope
        if (OnSlope() && !exitingSlope)
        {
            rb.AddForce(GetSlopeMoveDirection() * moveSpeed * 20f, ForceMode.Force);

            if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * 80f, ForceMode.Force);
        }

        // on ground
        else if (grounded)
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);

        // in air
        else if (!grounded)
            rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * airMultiplier, ForceMode.Force);

        // turn gravity off while on slope
        rb.useGravity = !OnSlope();
    }

    private void SpeedControl()
    {
        // limiting speed on slope
        if (OnSlope() && !exitingSlope)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.magnitude > moveSpeed)
                rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * moveSpeed;
        }

        // limiting speed on ground or in air
        else
        {
            Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

            // limit velocity if needed
            if (flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
            {
                Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        exitingSlope = true;

        // reset y velocity
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
    private void ResetJump()
    {
        readyToJump = true;

        exitingSlope = false;
    }

    private bool OnSlope()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out slopeHit, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.3f))
        {
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, slopeHit.normal);
            return angle < maxSlopeAngle && angle != 0;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private Vector3 GetSlopeMoveDirection()
    {
        return Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, slopeHit.normal).normalized;
    }

    private void StartSlide()
    {
        sliding = true;

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, slideYScale, transform.localScale.z);
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.down * 5f, ForceMode.Impulse);

        slideTimer = maxSlideTime;
    }

    private void SlidingMovement()
    {
        Vector3 inputDirection = orientation.forward;

        rb.AddForce(inputDirection.normalized * slideForce, ForceMode.Force);

        slideTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (slideTimer <= 0)
            StopSlide();
    }

    private void StopSlide()
    {
        sliding = false;

        transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, startYScale, transform.localScale.z);
    }
}
```

I have been trying for a very long time to fix this, although I'm not the best at coding. I decided to come onto stack overflow for some help. Thank you to everyone who tries to solves this problem :D. As the titles states everything here works, excluding the crouching, when I press ctrl my moveSpeed does not change to my crouchSpeed...

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Comment: Do not add `Solved` to your title ... if you found a proper answer you can add it to your own question if you think it will help future readers ... if not rather close the question